# Marketing Cloud Cordova SDK notification only showing silently

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, push-notification, cordova

We are using the [Marketing Cloud SDK Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin) in our app. Registering the contactKey works fine but when we send the push notification, although device is receiving it, we don't get a Pop up notification on the Android device. Instead we get an additional icon appearing in status bar. When the device has sound on, we hear the sound but no popup.

It is the same when the device is locked, it doesn't wake up the device, it simply shows the notification in the status bar at the top of the device.

In both cases we can see the notification when we slide down Android menu from top.

Before using Marketing Cloud SDK we've tested using Firebase Messaging SDK, and the push notifications worked as expected with the popup.

Comment: Open a support case.  There are no bugs that would result in this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, we have a support case open but not getting anywhere so i thought i would try on here

Comment: We can't seem to find the documents for the cordova plugin. is it limited compared to the native android?

Comment: I think you're confusing the types of notifications.  Push notifications, on Android, do not have a "pop up".  They show a notification in the status bar and are visible when the notification shade is opened (ref. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications).  InApp Notifications will result in a "pop up" being displayed (ref. https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging).

Comment: With regards to your other 2 comments: No, the Cordova plugin simply uses our SDK which simply uses Firebase.  If you're not getting the results you need out of the Support Case then you should request that it be escalated, however, in this case, there is nothing wrong ;)